# Problem with finding index of element from mongo database

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, indexing

I have a really weird problem, don't know what to do next. On the show page of territory in my app, I try to implement the previous/next feature to quickly switch between territories. So in the controller, I try to find an index of the current territory. The problem is, I always get -1, though when I console.log array, an element is there. Current version of controller:

```js
export const renderTerritoryHistory = (req, res, next) => {
    Territory
        .findById(req.params.territory_id)
        .populate(["preacher", "history"])
        .exec()
        .then((territory) => {
            Territory
                .find({congregation: req.user._id})
                .exec()
                .then((territories) => {
                    console.log(territories);
                    const currentIndex = territories.findIndex(t => t._id === mongoose.Types.ObjectId(territory._id));
                    console.log(currentIndex);
                    res.render("./territories/show", {
                        header: `Teren nr ${territory.number} | Territory Manager`,
                        territory: territory,
                        countDaysFromNow: countDaysFromNow,
                        currentUser: req.user,
                        currentIndex: currentIndex,
                        territories: territories
                    })
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: try: t._id.toString() === territory._id.toString()

Comment: i think 'mongoose.Types.ObjectId' will create a new object and when you compare object to object it will not references